# Paypal buy now form with sending emails

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

I have a form that collects data on a persons car (year, color, class, last 4 digits of vin. That same form also has information on the person registering for this event.

When the user clicks the paypal buy now button it should send an email to the person who is accepting the forms as well as redirect the user to paypal so the user can pay the registration fee.

You will see a submit button as well as a buy now button. I basically want the functionality of the submit but the redirection to paypal like the buy now button. Also not sure what the action should be on the form.

```
<div id="container">
<section id="register">

                 <form action="mail.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" on>
                        <h4>Your Jeep</h4>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Year</label>
                            <input value="" placeholder="Year" type="text" name="year">
                        </fieldset>



                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Color</label>
                            <input value="" placeholder="Color" type="text" name="color">
                        </fieldset>



                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Class</label>
                            <input value="" placeholder="Stock, Modified, Highly Modified" type="text" name="class">
                        </fieldset>


                   <!--------------------
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Class</label>
                            <select class="form-field">
                            <option value="Select Class">Select Class</option>
                            <option value="Stock">Stock</option>
                            <option value="Modified">Modified</option>
                            <option value="Highly Modified">Highly Modified</option>
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                     ------------------------->


                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Last 4 digits of VIN</label>
                            <input value="" placeholder="Last 4 digits of VIN" type="text" name="vin">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>





                            <h4>You</h4>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input value="" placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name">
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-field">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <input value="" placeholder="Address" type="text" name="address">
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-field">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label>City</label>
                                <input value="" placeholder="City" type="text" name="city">
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-field">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label>State</label>
                                <input value="" placeholder="State" type="text" name="state">
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-field">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label>Zip</label>
                                <input value="" placeholder="Zip" type="text" name="Zip">
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-field">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input value="" placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email">
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>


                       <div class="form-button">
                                <input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submit();"></div>
                       </form>










         <div id="paykim">
            <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Jeep Registration">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
        <p>Clicking the Submit button will bring you to the official PayPal website where you will be able to send the $10 Registration Fee to </p>
        <p id="ekim">Email of person accepting the registrations.</p>
        <p id="confirm">You'll recieve a conformation email once your transaction is complete.</p>
         </div> 



                 </section> 
      </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BsVv5/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will be store the data in a database. I recommend that first save your form data in the database, Once stored, create a checkout page by querying the database and creates the additional form of paypal. you will require documentation of ipn paypal for sending instant notifications.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: I should have mentioned that nothing is being saved into a database. Just going to the person with the email and they are keeping track of who has sent them the email.